# google cloud console oauth consent screen verification and oauth user cap

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, scopes

I'm having trouble understanding the oauth user cap. My app has no sensitive or restricted scopes requested but I'm still seeing the user cap indicator saying 7/100. The console says my app doesn't need verification. If I publish my app to the play store, will only 100 users be able to use it? How does this work? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to Protect users Google has given the [Upcoming Policy Enforcement Notice](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) which is to protect Google systems from abuse, apps that use OAuth and Cloud Identity have certain quota restrictions based on the risk level of the OAuth scopes an app uses.

If your app remains unverified, the unverified app screen will be displayed before the consent screen, and your app will be limited to 100 new users until it is verified. So As per this statement from Policy Enforcement you can use only 100 users. Refer this [Doc](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) for steps to verify your app under Verification for apps Field.

Comment: So even if the app says it doesn't require verification, the app will still be limited to 100 users until it is verified?

Comment: @ElliotScher : Yes, It is limited to 100 users only  and also have a check on [exceptions-to-verification-requirements](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Cexceptions-to-verification-requirements)

Comment: Thanks!! How can I verify my project if I'm not using any restricted or sensitive scopes? I don't see a submit for verification option unless these scopes are active. Am I missing something in the console?

Comment: @ElliotScher : As far i know, you need to  Add one or more sensitive scopes to the "Scopes for Google APIs" section of your OAuth consent screen settings or else if you are having any URLs with HTTP then move it to HTTPS.  Then you will be getting the "Submit for verification" button  enabled on the screen. Post done verification you can use increase quota for user caps.